# How to get an element by its style : position left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this bloc , it's a slider element :

```
<div id="sliderDispo" class="slider slider-dispo" data-slider-init="" data-slider-color="#0077b5 #EC6E31 #E40B0B" data-slider-step="33" >
                <div class="slider__interval">
                         <span>Oui</span>
                         <span>-3mois</span>
                         <span>-6mois</span>
                         <span>Non</span>
               </div>
    /***** want to recuper those 2 elements 
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 0%; left: 0%;"></div>
    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span>
    *********/
</div>
```

And i wanna recuper the 2 elements  **DIV and span** which are already prè-commented .

i have developped this fonction , where  i have tried to filter out the elements which have the  specific value of style : **style="left: 0%** (the Div & the span)  . and i need that to change the style in those elements

***My function:***

```
 function () {
            var initDsiponibilite = $("#inputDisponibilite").attr("value");
            alert(initDsiponibilite);
            $("#sliderDispo").attr("data-slider-init",initDsiponibilite);
            $.each( $("#sliderDispo").children().find().position.css('left','0%'))
            {
                $(this).attr("style","left:60%")
            }
```

**But that didn't work,  , any suggestions ????**

Comment: Any reason not to give these elements a proper class or id, and use it to find them later?

Comment: yeah i need to not give any ids or classes

Comment: first off html comments are `<!-- -->` not `/* */`

Comment: Secondly what does this `$("#inputDisponibilite").attr("value");` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```js
$("#sliderDispo")
  .children()
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).css("left") === "0%"; })
  .each(function(){ $(this).css("left", "60%"); });

console.log($("div.ui-slider-range")[0].style.left);
```

```html
<div
  id="sliderDispo"
  class="slider slider-dispo"
  data-slider-init=""
  data-slider-color="#0077b5 #EC6E31 #E40B0B"
  data-slider-step="33">

  <div class="slider__interval">
    <span>Oui</span>
    <span>-3mois</span>
    <span>-6mois</span>
    <span>Non</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Begin: want to recuper those 2 elements -->
  <div
    class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min"
    style="width: 0%; left: 0%;"></div>
  <span
    class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
    tabindex="0"
    style="left: 0%;"></span>
  <!-- End: want to recuper those 2 elements -->

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```